# Highcharts: saving canvas image as local file in IE

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to code a javascript function that takes a Highcharts image, converts it to canvas, and downloads the file image locally (without going to the server).

My problem is specifically with IE. I tried using msSaveBlob with Blob and MSBlobBuilder; in the first case the file downloads however the content is incorrect (the image is damaged when opened).

Fist code uses Blob/msSaveBlob ([see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/PDnmQ/356/), run with IE):

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");     
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    return navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([image],{type:"image/jpeg"}),"file23.jpeg");
}
```

Second code uses MSBlobBuilder/msSaveBlob but doesn't generate a file ([see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PDnmQ/359/), run with IE):

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"); 
if (window.MSBlobBuilder) {
    var bb = new MSBlobBuilder();
    bb.append(image);
    return navigator.msSaveBlob(bb, "file24.jpeg");
}
```

Any ideas how to make any of these work? Is there a preferred method? I understand this will work for IE10+ only.

Comment: You jsFiddle links are 404.  Also, how are you getting the canvas from Highcharts SVG?

Comment: Not sure what happened with jsFiddle, here you go again (canvas generated from highcharts and image downloaded with msSaveBlob) http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/u7sxqu2e/1/  run with IE10

Comment: small fix to the link above http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/u7sxqu2e/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`toDataURL` produces a base64 string of the PNG.  You need the raw data (or [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)), though.

From this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx):

> By using canvas.toDataURL(), you preclude the possibility of easily
>   using another application to view a saved drawing. Saving the drawing
>   as a PNG file has the benefit of allowing a number of standard
>   applications, including the browser, to display the drawing. By
>   switching to canvas.msToBlob(), we can save the file directly to
>   PNG...

So:

```
 canvg(canvas, svg);
 image = canvas.msToBlob();            
 if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
     return navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([image],                       
                                    {type:"image/png"}),"file23.png");
 }
```

Update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7sxqu2e/3/).

**EDITS**

For a more universal way to convert base64 images to blobs see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/16363).

And an example of how to do it in this workflow:

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL( "image/jpeg" );
image = b64toBlob(image.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,",""),"image/jpeg")

if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    return navigator.msSaveBlob(image,"file23.jpeg");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Is there a way to save a JPEG? msToBlob() seems to work only with PNG

Comment: @ps0604, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/u7sxqu2e/4/,  it borrows from the awesome answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/16363